# How can I prevent the Charm bar from showing up in my Java application?

Tags: java, swing, windows-8.1, tablet, kiosk

I've got a Java swing program that runs in full screen mode. It's effectively a kiosk program in that I want it to lock out everything else while it's running. This is running on a Windows 8.1 tablet, so of course the tablet is touchscreen, and therefore if you do an "edge swipe" (drag your finger from the right) the charms bar pops up and you can get to the Start screen from there. Is there some way to disable this from happening in Java? (Or is there some third-party solution not involving Java that can work in tandem to achieve the same result?)

Comment: Can you run a tablet in kiosk mode?

Comment: AFAIK, Microsoft's Kiosk mode ONLY works with Metro Apps (which are written in C#, not Java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to write a batch script that kills `explorer.exe` and then re-spawns it after the app exits, based on [this answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/714822/#803049).

Answer (score 0):

You can disable edge gestures while your app is active and full screen by setting the [System.EdgeGesture.DisableTouchWhenFullScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj553591(v=vs.85).aspx) property on the window.

I don't know if Java provides a direct way to set this (probably not), but you should be able to set this from a JNI.

Here's a C++ snippet from the [DisableTouchWhenFullScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj553591(v=vs.85).aspx) docs:

```
HRESULT SetTouchDisableProperty(HWND hwnd, BOOL fDisableTouch)
{
    IPropertyStore* pPropStore;
    HRESULT hrReturnValue = SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow(hwnd, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pPropStore));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hrReturnValue))
    {
        PROPVARIANT var;
        var.vt = VT_BOOL;
        var.boolVal = fDisableTouch ? VARIANT_TRUE : VARIANT_FALSE;
        hrReturnValue = pPropStore->SetValue(PKEY_EdgeGesture_DisableTouchWhenFullscreen, var);
        pPropStore->Release();
    }
    return hrReturnValue;
}
```